# Map discrepant variables between two data frames using a third data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2` of identical structure. The first three columns, `id`, `form`, and `instance` identify the participant and form(s). The remaining variable columns, `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`, contain analytic data and are largely identical except for a few slight discrepancies.

I have a third data frame, `map` that identifies the id, form(s), and variables that have discrepancies, but does not contain the values of these discrepancies. I would like to use the `map` data to create a final data frame, `df.final` that appends two columns and places the discrepant values from `df1` and `df2`.

Below I am providing sample data as well as a clunky `for` loop that creates the desired `df.final`, but it is very slow (takes several hours to run on the full dataset) - so slow in fact it is functionally unusable (this ideally needs to be updated in near real time). I am hoping someone better at coding than me can provide alternative, faster solutions.

(Note that given the simplicity of the example data, there are alternate ways to compare `df1` and `df2`, but assume these don't work and using `map` is the only option.)

```
# Example data, df1
df1 <- data.frame(id = rep(sprintf("K00%s", 0:9), each = 3),
                  form = rep(c("A","B", "B"), times = 10),
                  instance = rep(c("None", "1", "2"), times = 10),
                  var1 = sample(LETTERS, 30, replace = TRUE),
                  var2 = rnbinom(30, mu = 1, size = 0.02),
                  var3 = sample(c("Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"), 30, replace = TRUE))

# Sample data df2, same as df1 but with slight discrepancies
df2 <- df1
df2[15, 4] <- "A"
df2[c(4, 6, 8), 5] <- c(11,15,16)
df2[27:28, 6] <- "Bannanas"

# Example "Map" that only indicates what ID, form, instance, and variable is discrepant
map <- data.frame(id = c("K004", "K001", "K001", "K002", "K008", "K009"),
                  form = c("B","A", "B", "B", "B", "A"),
                  instance = c("2", "None", "2", "1", "2", "None"),
                  variable = c("var1", rep("var2", 3), "var3", "var3"))

# id form instance variable
# 1 K004    B        2     var1
# 2 K001    A     None     var2
# 3 K001    B        2     var2
# 4 K002    B        1     var2
# 5 K008    B        2     var3
# 6 K009    A     None     var3

## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
# Attempt, but VERY slow in full data
## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

df.final <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 6))

for (i in 1:nrow(map)){
  keepcols <- c("id", "form","instance", map[i,4])
  m1 <- merge(map[i,], df1[ , keepcols], by = keepcols[-4])
  m2 <- merge(m1, df2[, keepcols], by = keepcols[-4])
  df.final[i,] <- m2
}
names(df.final) <- c(names(map), "df1_entry","df2_entry")
df.final

#   id     form instance variable      df1_entry df2_entry
# 1 K004    B        2     var1         P         A
# 2 K001    A     None     var2         0        11
# 3 K001    B        2     var2         0        15
# 4 K002    B        1     var2         0        16
# 5 K008    B        2     var3     Pears  Bannanas
# 6 K009    A     None     var3    Apples  Bannanas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use your `map` frame, so my apologies if I have not answered your question, but I didn't think you needed it. I believe this does what you want:

```
inner_join(
  df1 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("var"),as.character)) %>% pivot_longer(cols=var1:var3,values_to = "df1"),
  df2 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("var"),as.character)) %>% pivot_longer(cols=var1:var3, values_to="df2"),
  on=c("id","form","instance","name")
) %>% filter(df1!=df2)
```

Output:

```
  id    form  instance name  df1    df2     
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   
1 K001  A     None     var2  0      11      
2 K001  B     2        var2  0      15      
3 K002  B     1        var2  0      16      
4 K004  B     2        var1  J      A       
5 K008  B     2        var3  Apples Bannanas
6 K009  A     None     var3  Apples Bannanas
```

If you absolutely have to use `map`, but you have access to `df1` and `df2`, you can do this:

```
map %>%
  inner_join(
    df1 %>%
      mutate(across(starts_with("var"),as.character)) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols=var1:var3,values_to = "df1",names_to="variable"),
    by=c("id","form","instance","variable")
  ) %>% 
  inner_join(
    df2 %>%
      mutate(across(starts_with("var"),as.character)) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols=var1:var3,values_to = "df2",names_to="variable"),
    by=c("id","form","instance","variable")
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you - as I stated in the question, unfortunately these alternate approaches don’t work and I have to use map, but please keep this answer because it may be useful for others as it is quite elegant

Comment: I don't quite understand why you can't just use `df1` and `df2`, because your loop attempt references `df1` and `df2`.. However, if you have to use `map`, I've given an example

Comment: Perfect - yes the simplicity of this reprex makes it seem silly to use `map` but I'll spare you the details - you nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In case this might be useful, you can do the following in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

merge(
  melt(df1, 1:3), 
  melt(df2, 1:3), 
  by = c("id", "form", "instance", "variable")
)[value.x != value.y]
```

**Output**

```
     id form instance variable value.x  value.y
1: K001    A     None     var2       1       11
2: K001    B        2     var2      22       15
3: K002    B        1     var2       0       16
4: K004    B        2     var1       S        A
5: K008    B        2     var3 Oranges Bannanas
6: K009    A     None     var3   Pears Bannanas
```